# I want to compare my awk result with a specific value by if condition

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, disk-usage

I have the result in below command. They are capacity of drives I want to compare to a threshold value. So I want to compare each line to a specific value. If greater then some condition follows.

```
df -kP | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//g'|sed -n '1!p'
```

Output of this command is like this :

```
36
0
19
36
36
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it all in awk:

```
df -kP | awk 'NR > 1 { gsub("%","",$5); if (0 + $5 > 90) { system("echo " $6 " is too high") }}'
```

Here we're manipulating `$5` as you were before, but using `gsub()` to strip off the `%` sign, `NR > 1` to take care of the `sed`, and after forcing $5 to be seen as integer, we compare it to a magic value of 90; if true, then we call out a system command (echo).

Comment: That just works fine thanks for the answer But I will be storing above command in a variable and then comparing it like this: `file_usage=$( df -kP | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//g'|sed -n '1!p')`